# Temporarily combine Google Analytics segments for reporting

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, advanced-segments

When using segments in Google Analytics reports, they are always applied to the data as an "or" operator to compare (understandably so), but I'm looking for a way to apply them temporarily as an "and".

This is a hypothetical situation, so the following segment examples could be different based on what I need for the report.

If I have a segment of users who arrived at my site on a specific page, and another segment for users who share a custom dimension- when I add the segments I'm seeing data for both segments individually. What I want to see is combined data.

I know I could make another segment, a custom report, or even a filter to view data the way I am asking, but let's say I have a whole bunch of different variations I want to see? Is there a less time-consuming way to do this?